# What does "on numerous house-calls" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

What does **on** mean here?

**Dr. Fischer had resisted accepting money from the poor woman on numerous house-calls.**

Does it mean *after*?

Would you kindly paraphrase the sentence?

Comment: It means "at the time of" in this usage.

Comment: I would paraphrase the sentence as **"Dr. Fischer made many house-calls and resisted accepting money from the poor woman when he visited her."** It's not a better way to say it, but it might be easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"On numerous [events]" is an idiomatic phrase  that means "multiple times" or "on multiple occasions".

So the doctor has made many house-calls, but resisted being paid for them (when he was there).

Comment: Does *resisting* implies that *he liked to receive it but he stood against getting the money*?

Comment: I'd say he refused payment because the woman was poor. Think of the following image: The woman tries to give him some money, but he won't take it.